# Typescript: Convert '28/11/2019 00:00:00.000' format to timestamp

Tags: angular, typescript

How to convert date with milliseconds in typescript(Angular)

for example convert `28/11/2019 00:00:00.000` to a timestamp

Comment: use date pipe : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Try new Date("your date").getTime(); it will give you the timestamp. But before that you need to convert it to date format.

Comment: i found a solution const timestamp = moment(dateFormatValue, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS').unix() * 1000 +
            moment(dateFormatValue, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS').milliseconds();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string `"28/11/2019 00:00:00.000"` into a date first, then you can get the milliseconds. To convert the data from string to a Date object, you can use `moment` package from npm.

Then use as :

```
 var momObject = moment("28/11/2019 00:00:00.000",'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss')
```

will give you a `Moment` object. Then use js `Date` class to get time in `ms`:

```
new Date(momObj.toISOString()).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `28/11/2019 00:00:00.000` into :

`2019-11-28T00:00:00` and then you can use `new Date(myDate).getTime() / 1000`